# Local language replacement is not complete

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm new to Forge, and I would like to build a offline 3d viewer with my server, but the language option is not totally functional, like the screenshot below:

[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a7as.png)

The language only in cube is same with the browser configuration (Chinese in picture) , others are all default English words.

All the .js/.css file is stored on server, and if I set the option in `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({language: '***someLanguage***'})`. it's only works in the cube, others are still English.

But if I change the main js file source to AutoDesk's CDN below(other js files still on local server) https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v3.3 (both of the versions are same within offline and online), the language will completely be replaced by option and works right.

For reproducing the problem, you can export a model from https://extract.autodesk.io/, then run the download files in a local http server.

In china we got bad connection with oversea server, so I would prefer local storage for better UE, are there some get/post requests should be handled on local, and I missed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with `language: 'zh-Hans'` and worked fine, also tried and Chinese (seems fine). Using **Viewer v6**. As per license you should be using the .js file from Autodesk hosted URL (i.e. CDN):

> The Autodesk Forge viewer can only be used to view files generated by Autodesk Forge services. The Autodesk Forge Viewer JavaScript must be delivered from an Autodesk hosted URL.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Augusto. I see, the *.js file **must be loaded from Autodesk host**, I think I should give up to localize the *.js static file on my server by sacrificing the speed.